# Using git between 2 different machines and github

Tags: git, github

Lately, if I do:
 1. git push origin master (on my laptop)
 2. git pull origin master (on my Mac)
 3. git status (on my Mac)

I see 'your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 6 commits'.  Since I haven't made any commits on the Mac, this seems to be an error; or something I don't quite understand.

If I then do:
4. git push origin master (on my Mac)

The ahead of origin/master message goes away.

Note that in the above steps, I have made no commits/modifications on the Mac, between steps 1 & 2.

It's happening all the time at the moment - should I be worried, or is there a reasonable explanation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stop typing `git pull origin master`. That instructs git to pull the contents of the master branch on the origin repo into your local branch, completely bypassing the remote-tracking branch. Instead you should just type `git pull`. This will pull the branch set in `branch.master.merge` (assuming "master" is checked out) from the remote repo and use it to update the remote-tracking branch, and then it will merge that remote-tracking branch into your local branch.

To clarify how it works, `git pull <args>` runs `git fetch <args>` and then uses git-merge to merge the fetched branch(es) into the current branch. If you specify `git fetch`, git will fetch the default remote and update the remote-tracking branches, at which point git-pull will merge in the correct branch. But if you specify `git fetch origin master`, git will fetch the master branch of the origin repo and store it in FETCH_HEAD without updating the remote-tracking branches. You can verify this yourself by typing `git fetch origin master` (assuming there are remote commits you don't have). The end result of the fetch should be a line like

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

This tells you that the remote branch "master" was fetched and stored in FETCH_HEAD. On the other hand if you simply type `git fetch origin` you should see something more like

```
 * branch            master     -> origin/master
```

This tells you that the remote branch "master" was fetched and stored in the local remote-tracking branch "origin/master".

Comment: Will try to digest this; there's obviously a hole in my understanding of how this stuff works.  So it is OK to do git push origin master?  Or should that always be git push too?

Comment: Use git push to update all the tracked branches to their remotes. Use git push origin master to only push particular branches.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **git push** , but before configure it

> git config -- global push.default matching/upstream